# Usar uma variavel int de uma form em outro form C#

Tags: c#, variáveis

Eu tenho tentado usar minha variavel double dinheiro do form1 no form2, pois preciso do valor recebido no form1 no form2, eu deixei a variavel publica e tentei instanciar mas continua dando erro:
codigo no form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public double dinheiro = 0;
  public  Boolean jogar = false;
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bnjogar.Visible = false;
        label4.Visible = false;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dinheiro = 1.75;
         String i = Convert.ToString(dinheiro);


        Dinheira.Text = "$" + dinheiro;
        jogar = true;
        if(jogar == true)
        {
            bnjogar.Visible = true;
            label4.Visible = true;
        }





    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 form3 = new Form3();
        form3.ShowDialog();

    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();

        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

}

e no form2 esta assim

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    int dinheiro2;
    Form1 meuform = new Form1();
    public Form2()

    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         dinheiro2 = meuform.dinheiro;  
    }
}
```

}

se alguem puder me ajudar por favor

Comment: Dentro do form2 não é necessário criar uma instância de form1, o que você fez foi criar um outro form1 diferente do form1 que chamou o form2. Vou direto ao ponto, passe o valor da variável dinheiro por parâmetro que resolverá seu problema. 
Ex:
 public Form2(int dinheiro) { dinheiro2 = dinheiro}

private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(dinheiro);
        form2.Show();

        this.Hide();
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes fazer de várias formas.

Uma delas é passar os valores no construtor do seu form:

```
//Isso você faz no Form1
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Aqui você constrói o form passando o valor por parâmetro 
    new Form2(dinheiro).Show();
}

//Isso é no Form2
public Form2(double valor)
{
    //Aqui você pode pegar o valor e armazenar em outro lugar
    InitializeComponent();            
}
```

Da pra fazer buscando diretamente do seu form1:

```
//Isso é no Form1
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Aqui você diz que o form1 é o "dono" desse form2
    new Form2().Show(this);
}

//Isso é no Form2
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnShown(e); 

    //Aqui o Owner é o form1, você pode fazer Cast para ele e acessar o que precisa
    //Funciona também em outros métodos do form2
    var dinheiro = (Owner as Form1)?.dinheiro;
}
```

Comment: Funcionoou perfeitamente, Muito obrigado

Comment: Show de bola, valeu